Calculating the pdf of transformed random variables with non-invertible Jacobian matrix
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables and $p_{(X,Y)}(x,y)$ be the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$. Suppose that $(X,Y)$ transformed to $(X,X)$. We want to calculate the joint pdf of transformed random variables.
From this, we know that as we normally take $g(X,Y)=U$ and $h(X,Y)=V$. This gives us that, using the $g(X,Y)=X=h(X,Y)$, we get $U=V$. Also the corresponding Jacobian matrix can be given as
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
But this is non-invertible. I have problem in computing the joint pdf of the transformed random variables. I also see online and come to know that the joint pdf of $(X,X)$ is $p_{X}(x)\delta(x-y)$. Here I am not able to calculate the $\delta$ from the usual methods. Also I have calculated the first cdf as $P(X<x,Y<y)=P(X<x,X<y)=P(X<\min(x,y))$. From this cdf, can I calculate the desired pdf?

There is no joint pdf of $(X,X)$; it has a singular distribution.

Can you provide some suggestion for the pdf derivation of this problem?

According to singular defination of wikipedia, A distribution is singular if the probability distribution is concentrated on a set of lebesgue measure zero but in this problem I didnt take support of random variables X and Y on a set of lebesgue measure zero. Then how to proceed?

$(X, X)$ has support in ${(x,x), x\in\mathbb{R}}$ whose lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is equal to $0$.

@rezoons How to transform $p_{XY}(x,y)$ to obtain $p_{X,X}(x,x)$, any way out using the singular distribution concept?
